# Qt Designer with VS 2012/2013

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

I'm learning Qt and using it as addin to VS 2013. My problem occurs while using Qt Designer: in context menu to any object, I can't find the "go to slot" option, as it is described in [Getting Started Tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/gettingstartedqt.html). I'm pretty sure, that it's a matter of using vs2013 addin. My question is: is there any way to fix this bug? Or I just have to add any slots manualy?

I have found some similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227993/qt-designer-missing-go-to-slot-in-context-menu) and [here](http://arroyjose.blogspot.com/2013/06/adding-custom-slot-in-qt-designer-and.html), but these are quite old articles (1 and 2 year old), so I suppose that something has changed since then...

Comment: Don't bother using Qt Creator for connecting signals and slots. Adding them directly in your code gives you much more flexibility and readability.

Comment: @user3564091 Ok, so how to do it properly? Is it like this: after defining the widget, I define a _private slot_ in header file, eg. `private void on_quitButton_clicked();`, and then in cpp file I fill the body `Class::on_quitButton_clicked(){}`. Next, as far as I know, I have to make the widget understand, that it shall invoke this particular slot. How to do it? In signal/slot editor in QtDesigner?

Comment: This is basically all you need to know to start: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html