# "Go to slot" in Qt Designer (not Qt Creator)

Tags: visual-studio, qt, designer

Okay, so here it is. I've got Qt add-in installed to my VS 2012. I edit UIs with Qt designer. And I've got Pushbutton, which I want to use. Everyone says `right-click->go to slot` and pufff, your code appears. But here's the thing: `Go to slot` option does not appear when I right click. Is it because I dont use full Creator? How can I do this in VS?

Comment: This should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227993/qt-designer-missing-go-to-slot-in-context-menu

Comment: I know this, I define methods by myself, just wanted to know if there's a way to do it easier

Comment: So your slots are named with the right nomenclature for `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName` to work?